# Tensorflow Training Stops before all epochs are completed, with no error message

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, attention-model

I was trying to train a multi-head attention model on some open angle data that I had generated, for a classification problem. The model was meant to test for testing what normalizations to use for my data, which can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SQYVOGaug3wXPjTq3LJpOEcGeASPxu3J?usp=sharing). A colab notebook with the relevant code can also be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KPJTIflp97DE-dj2eh3UObu1A3twBhz6?usp=sharing).

I was trying to train the model over 90 epochs but each time after somewhere between 15 and 25 epochs the model crashes out with no error message.

Here is a snippet of the output

```
Epoch 14/90
491/491 [==============================] - 60s 122ms/step - loss: 0.9339 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5995 - val_loss: 0.9894 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5867
Epoch 15/90
491/491 [==============================] - 60s 122ms/step - loss: 0.9312 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5992 - val_loss: 0.9819 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5898
116/116 [==============================] - 6s 54ms/step - loss: 0.9647 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5941
```

I have tried running the code on a Google Compute Engine GPU through colab as well as on my local system in a wsl2 environment, each attempt giving me the same results. The same problem occurs even if I don't normalize the data.

Tech Specs:
Windows 11 Home
AMD ryzen 7 5800H
Nvidia RTX 3050 mobile
16GB RAM
VSCode on WSL2
Google Colab with a Python 3 Google Compute Engine backend (GPU)

Comment: Your training is stopping early because you are using `EarlyStopping` callback. `callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)]`. Do you need this?

Comment: Hello thank you very much, I somehow completely missed that I had included this code.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Djinn in the comments I hadn't noticed that I had my callbacks set to EarlyStopping which caused my model to stop training when my metrics stopped improving.